# How do I search for a user or id in django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am trying to make a view to add an user.

I want it to be added by `id` or by `username`, but I am getting an error every time I search to find out if the user exists:

```
try:
    user = User.objects.filter(Q(id=user_s['id']) | Q(username=user_s['username']))
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    ... rest of the code ...
```

This throws:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Usuario1'
```

Comment: Try to print and check the value of `user_s['id']`, it has to be a number.

Comment: Yeah your passing 'Usario1' as a int. So likely your dictionary is set up wrong and your pulling the user name for the id and vise versa